# How can I take MySQL dumps with some tables excluded from the database

Tags: mysql, database

We have a database in which one specific table gets very large very fast. When taking a dump and then restoring this database on another server, it takes a lot of time due to the large size. I want to exclude this specific table when taking the dump. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump has a [`--ignore-table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table) option, something like:

```
mysqldump -p -u username nameofdatabase --ignore-table=verybigtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the --ignore-table flag.

```
  --ignore-table=name Do not dump the specified table. To specify more than one
                      table to ignore, use the directive multiple times, once
                      for each table.  Each table must be specified with both
                      database and table names, e.g.,
                      --ignore-table=database.table.
```

Answer (score 0):

Most graphical clients (like phpmyadmin) give you exclusion options.